# Android webview javascript continues after URL change, making it slow down over time

Tags: android

When loading a lot of web pages into a WebView, it seems that the JavaScript part of the web pages don't behave like in a PC browser - it keeps running after switching URL, and basically makes the WebView experience slower and slower for that reason.

Has anybody else experienced this or something similar on Android 2.1 and found a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a bit different: It was when the activity was changed using an intent, and then it switched back to the activity that contained the WebView - then, the previous background javascript code was still running.

The solution was to do a WebView.LoadData(') just before switching activity, that killed the background javascript thread.